# Fast way for python declare variable (convert Dataframe to numpy array)

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

Any way to reduce these code below? This code to declare variable base on `number_inputs`

```
if number_inputs == 1:
    data_input = data[['t-1']].values
elif number_inputs == 2:
    data_input = data[['t-2', 't-1']].values
elif number_inputs == 3:
    data_input = data[['t-3', 't-2', 't-1']].values
elif number_inputs == 4:
    data_input = data[['t-4', 't-3', 't-2', 't-1']].values
elif number_inputs == 5:
    data_input = data[['t-5', 't-4', 't-3', 't-2', 't-1']].values
elif number_inputs == 6:
    data_input = data[['t-6', 't-5', 't-4', 't-3', 't-2', 't-1']].values
elif number_inputs == 7:
    data_input = data[['t-7', 't-6', 't-5', 't-4', 't-3', 't-2', 't-1']].values
elif number_inputs == 8:
    data_input = data[['t-8','t-7', 't-6', 't-5', 't-4', 't-3', 't-2', 't-1']].values
elif number_inputs == 9:
    data_input = data[['t-9','t-7', 't-6', 't-5', 't-4', 't-3', 't-2', 't-1']].values
```

Comment: You mean pandas, not numpy? I'm struggling to understand how this code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = ['t-'+str(i) for i in range(1, 10)]    
for i in range(1, 10):
    if number == i: 
        data_input=data[x[i-1::-1]].values
```